# Bring Unity 's input source indicator for Gnome

Tags: unity, gnome, input-language

Is there any way to bring Unity 's input source indicator for Gnome?
Actually in Unity 7 input source indicator has a square shape around input source symbol, if you don't remember just see that:

[image]

Now is there any way to have it in Gnome?

Comment: I think if you have multiple layouts configured, you should see an item in the top panel to select between them. It doesn't have the icon like Unity did, but just the language code (en, ar, ja, etc).

Comment: @dobey: I read the question as if the OP talks about the look of the indicator, not its absence.

Comment: so, I can't bring the same in Gnome?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, since GNOME seems to display character(s), not an icon. Thus the style for the input menu is the same as for every other menu in the panel.